# Definite integral $\int_{-64}^{1}\frac{dx}{x^{1/3}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am having some trouble with a problem very similar to this in my study guide, how can I start, the $-64$ is really intimidating to me.

Comment: What is the antiderivative of $x^k$ ?

Comment: The integral is an *improper* integral, since our function blows up at $0$. But this improper integral converges.

Comment: @AndréNicolas. Could you interfere in this no end discussion ? Thanks.

Comment: What intervention do you suggest? The PV discussion is of no relevance because of the convergence.

Comment: @Brian. May I ask you a favor ? When you will get the "official" answer from your professor, could you add it to your post. I am really curious. Thanks and cheers :-)

Answer (score 5):

We have to break this up and take the limit.

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left (\int_{-64}^{-\epsilon}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}dx+\int^{1}_{\epsilon}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}dx \right )$$

Using the power rule,

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left (\left[\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{2}{3}} \right ]_{-64}^{-\epsilon}+\left [\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{2}{3}} \right ]^{1}_{\epsilon}\right )$$

This becomes

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left (\frac{3}{2}(-\epsilon)^{\frac{2}{3}}-\frac{3}{2}(64)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\frac{3}{2}1^{\frac{2}{3}} -\frac{3}{2}\epsilon^{\frac{2}{3}} \right )$$
Notice the cancellation of the $\epsilon$ terms.  So we are left with

$$=-\frac{3}{2}(4)^2+\frac{3}{2}=\frac{3}{2}(1-16)=-\frac{45}{2} $$

Comment: This is not correct, I am afraid.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I agree with you. This is Cauchy principal value.

Answer (score 1):

There's really nothing to be intimidated of. Once you realize that $1/x^{1/3} = x^{-1/3}$, you can just use power rule.

Edit: I just realized that you probably want to take the riemann sum and compute it manually. In that case, I would suggest integrating the inverse.

Comment: then would i just integrate?

Comment: The first step is to get the antiderivative. Then use bounds.

Comment: okay i got (3/2)-24(-1)^(2/3) thank you

Comment: could that be simplified in any way

Comment: uh.. (-1)^2/3 is 1. So you should get 3/2 - 24 = -45/2.

Comment: @thkim1011. Not sure at all !

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't realize that it's improper.

Comment: @thkim1011. The problem is not related to the improper nature of the integral but to the value.

Answer (score 0):

It is an improper integral . one may write $\int_{-64}^0x^\frac{-1}{3}dx+\int_{0}^1x^\frac{-1}{3}dx.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

First, the antiderivative $$\int\frac{dx}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}=\frac{3 x^{2/3}}{2}$$ Now, for the integral (taking into account André Nicolas's comment which does not need to be repeated), the result is then $$\frac{3}{2}\Big(1^{\frac{2}{3}}-(-64)^{\frac{2}{3}}\Big)=\frac{3}{2}\Big(1-(-64)^{\frac{2}{3}}\Big)$$ You were right to be "intimidated" by the $-64$ since $(-64)^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is a complex number which you need to simplify.

I suppose that this is the key part of the problem but I am sure that you can take from here.

**Added later to this answer**

I can accept to be totally wrong but, at least for me $$(-64)^{\frac{2}{3}}=-8+8 i \sqrt{3}$$

Comment: I don't see how $(-64)^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is a complex number

Comment: @Mr.T. OK, what is its value ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it may be motivated by the fact that you paid scant attention to the improperness (is that the right word?) around $x=0$. The continuity of your antiderivative does take care of the eventual problems, but ignoring the issue may press somebody's buttons.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen. I think that André Nicolas made the first point which I thought unecessary to repeat. What is amazing is that, up to now, no one noticed that the result of the integration is a complex.

Comment: Is it not true that $(-64)^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is $16$ in this situation? It's the integral over the real number set, and it's well-defined. Of course the structure $(-64)^{\frac{2}{3}}$ may be referred to a complex number, but this is not the case I think.
As I know, $(-4)^3=-64$ and $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ in this case is the third root of a real number. No complex needed

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen. Could you clarify ? I really do not understand what you mean. And, almost, don't worry : I take easy ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I hope I could be like you when I'm at your age. :-) Emotions... :))

Comment: The integral corresponds to a (signed) area of a measurable (though unbounded) region of the plane, so the answer is surely a real number. Also, it is important your antiderivative is continuous at $x=0$. That takes care of the 2-sided improperness.

Comment: $x^{1/3}$ when used as a real function is by convention assumed to be the real cube-root of $x$. So the function as given is well-defined everywhere except $0$ and has a real value. It is also continuous if the singularity is removed, so its integral also is real. There are no complex numbers involved.

Comment: By the way I'm not the downvoter but I suspect it's your mention of complex numbers that was the reason, not the continuity issue that Jyrki mentioned, which you also should have mentioned. The point is that the complex logarithm can be defined with different branches, and in different situations we need to use a different branch. Your value for the cube-root is just one of the three possible values. It happens that we can't have a branch of the complex logarithm such that the cube-root function agrees with the conventional real-valued cube-root, but we should recognize which is being used.

Comment: And sorry I made a mistake; the singularity isn't removable, but still the integral of the real function is real because it converges.